# Parsing JSON Array using Python Requests & Error Codes

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm attempting to parse a JSON array, however, I'm having some issues.
Here's my current code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json, requests
platformUrl = 'https://www.igbd.com/api/v1/platforms'
platformReq = requests.get(platformUrl, headers={'Authorization': 'Token token="1234"'})
platformData = json.loads(platformReq)#json.loads(platformReq.text)
platformList = data['platforms']

print platformList
```

The example output is:

> {"platforms":[{"id":32,"name":"Sega Saturn","slug":"saturn"},{"id":14,"name":"Mac","slug":"mac"},{"id":47,"name":"Virtual Console (Nintendo)","slug":"vc"}

I'm getting error:

> expected string or buffer

When I use this code, it works, but the output is wrong, and it's not meant for arrays:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json, requests

platformUrl = 'https://www.igdb.com/api/v1/platforms'
platformReq = requests.get(platformUrl, headers={'Authorization': 'Token token=1234"'})
platformData = platformReq.json()

print platformData
```

Here is the output with that code:

> {u'platforms': [{u'slug': u'saturn', u'id': 32, u'name': u'Sega Saturn'}, {u'slug': u'mac', u'id': 14, u'name': u'Mac'}, {u'slug': u'vc', u'id': 47, u'name': u'Virtual Console (Nintendo)'}

Bonus question: How would I handle errors for the request? 
Ex: 200 - everything's fine, 401 - not valid key, etc, etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you pass an `request` object in the `json.loads`

In the error it says that it needs a string or buffer instead. You can pass in the string from the request by doing:

```
json.loads(platformReq.text)
```

But `platformReq.json()` works the same way!

Hope that helps.

EDIT

To respond to your status code question (sorry didn't see it before). You can check the response status code like this:

```py
if platformReq.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    # Print the response
    print platformReq.json()
else:
    print "Something went wrong";
```

Comment: It still formats it weirdly when it prints it, it has the letter u before everything. See the first post.

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken that is because it is in unicode. This is not a bad thing, the computer can read that perfectly. BTW I edited my post, I didn't see your status code question.

Comment: If it gave me a specific status code, for example: 500. Could I specify what the issue is?

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken It means it has a Internal Server Error, that is on their side. Here is more information about status codes http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting a JSON response, the code that you have commented out should work:

```
    json.loads(platformReq.text)
```

The error you are getting is because json.loads() needs a string, not a response object.

As for the error handling I would recommend adding a check at the top of this for platformReg.status_code to make sure that it is equal to 200 before you proceed

Comment: What if I needed to push the error out to the webpage? For example, if it gives a 500 error how would I display that?

Comment: @AllTheGoodNamesWereTaken Assuming that this code is within a view, you could do something like:----

 `if platformReq.status_code == 500:` -----------------------------------------------------------------
    `return HttpResponse('500_error.html')` -------------------------------------------------------------

Your going to have to create that html page, but that's something you can do to display it.

If this is supposed to return JSON, replace the html page with a JSON object that has an error message in it that you check for on the front end.